# Can't use returned variable in another file - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I am trying to use a variable defined in one file (file1.py) in another file (file2.py).
File 1 contains "shoe" which is a queue, which has been tested and worked fine. So it does not look like the problem is with the implementation of the queue. 
Context on what the variable of issue is:
result is merely a shuffled list made out of another list called cardList. result is shuffled within the shuffle function. It is a local variable within the scope of shuff. To get around this, I did try using: `global result`, and then import it again, but it did not work, so I am probably using `global` wrong?

Here are what I have tried so far that don't work for me:
**In File1:** where `cardList` is a list of 120 items.

```
def shuff(deck): # this function works fine within file1
    for i in range(0, 9):
    result = []
    popped = cardList.pop(R.randint(0, len(cardList)-1))
    result = result.append(popped)

    return result

def main():
    shuff(cardList)
```

In **File2**

```
from File1 import result
```

The above does not work, so I looked around and followed an answer which said my variable needs to be in main(), so I tried the following:, in **File1**

```
def main():
    result = shuff(cardList)
```

I tried method 2 by removing the "return result" because I thought that it may override the existing result variable. But I also tried it without that, and both ways, it did not seem to work.

Lastly,
I made result a Global Var in File1 under the shuff function. And that did not seem to work either

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `from File1 import result` implies that `result` was declared as a variable or function somewhere in `File1`.  You have not given enough context to show us that this is true.  From what I see, `result` is only declared locally within `shuff` so the `import` call will surely fail.  Can you provide a [mcve] to show us what you're really trying to do?

Comment: @rayryeng-ReinstateMonica You are right that it is a local variable. And in my most recent try, I changed `result` to a global variable which I might not be implementing correctly since it won't work either.  I changed the code to get rid of non-obvious variables and parameters.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many issues at play here. For example, since **result** is not defined as a global variable, the variable only exists within your **shuff** function. Although method 2 is close to the answer, since your **main** is a function, again **result** only exists within that function and cannot be accessed from outside the function. If you want **from File1 import result** to work I suggest simply doing:

File 1:

```py
def shuff(deck): # this function works fine within file1
    for i in range(0, shoe.size()):
    result = []
    popped = cardList.pop(R.randint(0, len(cardList)-1))
    result = result.append(popped)

    return result

result = shuff(cardList)
```

File 2:

```py
from File1 import result
print(result)
```

If you want to keep your main function, do:

File 1:

```py
def main():
    return shuff(cardList)
```

File 2:

```py
from File1 import main
result = main()
print(result)
```

Ultimately, there are many ways of doing what you are trying to do, just pick one that applies to your needs

Comment: Thanks so much! This does work. And actually, it would seem that a third method combining the methods you provided works too:
`
def main*():
        return shuff(cardList)
`

`
from File1 import result
```